# Importing xlsx file into JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, excel, csv, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have been assigned a task to read data from **csv** and **xlsx** file and display it in **JQuery Datatables**.

I was be able to display csv file data using **JQuery-CSV** plugin but somehow i am unable to find any good solution to display an xlsx file data in JQuery DataTables.

Your suggestions are deeply appreciated....

Comment: Check this https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/jquery_datatables_and_dynamic_converter

Comment: Or this: https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/3375836